# Strange matter and star quakes

Tags: astrophysics, neutron-stars, exotic-matter

If neutron stars are able to form into strange matter at its core, wouldn’t this be enough to disrupt it and cause noticeable star quakes?
Edit: Could it cause it to go supernova?

I also know that it would be indistinguishable from a normal star quake, but I’m still curious to know it.

Thank you!

Also please know, I don’t know a lot on the subject (i.e., math, new-ish data, possibly huge new theories on the matter)

Comment: You asked a question earlier with practicaly the same title.  I'd suggest a little more thought about a suitable question title.  E.g. "strange matter and neutron star quakes".

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664944/2451